# Is it possible to query and set a viewpoint on a MATLAB 3D plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I've got a surfc plot, similar to this:

[image]

I want to manually set a custom viewpoint by panning and zooming with the MATLAB toolbar. After the suitable perspective is found, is it possible to store this viewpoint and apply it on other, similar plots? I want to create a plotsequence and therefore need a constant axis layout/ perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `view` command, you can query and set the current perspective, and with the `xlim`, `ylim`, and `zlim` command, you can query and set the current zoom.

For example

```
[az,el] = view; %# queries the perspective
view(az,el); %# sets the perspective

xl = xlim; %# queries the x-axis limits
xlim(xl); %# sets the x-axis limits
```

Alternatively, you can modify the `XData`, `YData`, `ZData` and possibly `CData` properties of your plot objects when you are updating plots in a sequence. This will be faster than recreating the figure, axes, and objects at each iteration.